# File Watchers not working in Intellij for isort and autoflake combination

Tags: intellij-idea, isort, autoflake

I have a Python file with multiline import statement:

```py
from itertools import (
    accumulate,
    chain,
    combinations,
    combinations_with_replacement,
    compress,
    count,
    islice,
    product
)
```

from which I try to remove unused imports by first changing multiline import statement to single-line imports:

```
isort -sl totest.py
autoflake --remove-all-unused-imports --remove-unused-variables -i totest.py
```

It works great in command line, but when using File Watchers in Intellij it does not run autoflake when saving file for the first time. Basically, to get around it I need to:

1. Make some edit, e.g., add some space
2. Save file
3. It gets formatted to:

   ```py
   from itertools import accumulate
   from itertools import chain
   from itertools import combinations
   from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
   from itertools import compress
   from itertools import count
   from itertools import islice
   from itertools import product
   ```
4. And then make another edit
5. Save file
6. And redundant imports gets removed

Steps 4 and 5 are redundant.

I wonder what could be the reason and where should I report that? To IDEA Intellij team, to isort or where?

Here's my `watchers.xml` to import into Intellij.

```xml
<TaskOptions>
  <TaskOptions>
    <option name="arguments" value="--remove-all-unused-imports --remove-unused-variables -i $FilePath$" />
    <option name="checkSyntaxErrors" value="true" />
    <option name="description" />
    <option name="exitCodeBehavior" value="ERROR" />
    <option name="fileExtension" value="py" />
    <option name="immediateSync" value="false" />
    <option name="name" value="Remove unused variables and imports" />
    <option name="output" value="$FilePath$" />
    <option name="outputFilters">
      <array />
    </option>
    <option name="outputFromStdout" value="false" />
    <option name="program" value="autoflake" />
    <option name="runOnExternalChanges" value="true" />
    <option name="scopeName" value="Project Files" />
    <option name="trackOnlyRoot" value="false" />
    <option name="workingDir" value="" />
    <envs />
  </TaskOptions>
  <TaskOptions>
    <option name="arguments" value="-sp $$ProjectFileDir$/.isort.cfg $FilePath$" />
    <option name="checkSyntaxErrors" value="true" />
    <option name="description" />
    <option name="exitCodeBehavior" value="ERROR" />
    <option name="fileExtension" value="py" />
    <option name="immediateSync" value="false" />
    <option name="name" value="Organize imports" />
    <option name="output" value="$FilePath$" />
    <option name="outputFilters">
      <array />
    </option>
    <option name="outputFromStdout" value="false" />
    <option name="program" value="isort" />
    <option name="runOnExternalChanges" value="true" />
    <option name="scopeName" value="Project Files" />
    <option name="trackOnlyRoot" value="false" />
    <option name="workingDir" value="" />
    <envs />
  </TaskOptions>
  <TaskOptions>
    <option name="arguments" value="--config=&quot;$ProjectFileDir$&quot;/pyproject.toml $FilePath$" />
    <option name="checkSyntaxErrors" value="true" />
    <option name="description" />
    <option name="exitCodeBehavior" value="ERROR" />
    <option name="fileExtension" value="py" />
    <option name="immediateSync" value="false" />
    <option name="name" value="Format code (with Black)" />
    <option name="output" value="$FilePath$" />
    <option name="outputFilters">
      <array />
    </option>
    <option name="outputFromStdout" value="false" />
    <option name="program" value="black" />
    <option name="runOnExternalChanges" value="true" />
    <option name="scopeName" value="Project Files" />
    <option name="trackOnlyRoot" value="false" />
    <option name="workingDir" value="" />
    <envs />
  </TaskOptions>
</TaskOptions>
```